# How can I combine two scalaz streams with a predicate selector?

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz-stream

I would like to combine two scalaz streams with a predicate which selects the next element from either stream. For instance, I would like this test to pass:

```
val a = Process(1, 2, 5, 8)
val b = Process(3, 4, 5, 7)

choose(a, b)(_ < _).toList shouldEqual List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8)
```

As you can see, we can't do something clever like `zip` and order the two elements because one of the processes may be selected consecutively at times.

I took a stab at a solution that I thought would work. It compiled! But damn it if it doesn't do anything. The JVM just hangs :(

```
import scalaz.stream.Process._
import scalaz.stream._

object StreamStuff {
  def choose[F[_], I](a:Process[F, I], b:Process[F, I])(p: (I, I) => Boolean): Process[F, I] =
    (a.awaitOption zip b.awaitOption).flatMap {
      case (Some(ai), Some(bi)) =>
        if(p(ai, bi)) emit(ai) ++ choose(a, emit(bi) ++ b)(p)
        else emit(bi) ++ choose(emit(ai) ++ a, b)(p)
      case (None, Some(bi)) => emit(bi) ++ b
      case (Some(ai), None) => emit(ai) ++ a
      case _ => halt
    }
}
```

Note that the above was my second attempt. In my first attempt I tried to create a `Tee` but I couldn't figure out how to un-consume the loser element. I felt that I needed something recursive like I have here.

I am using streams version `0.7.3a`.

Any tips (including incremental hints because I'd like to simply learn how to figure these things out on my own) are greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 5):

I'll give a couple of hints and an implementation below, so you might want to cover the screen if you want to work out a solution yourself.

Disclaimer: this is just the first approach that came to mind, and my familiarity with the scalaz-stream API is a little rusty, so there may be nicer ways to implement this operation, this one might be totally wrong in some horrible way, etc.

### Hint 1

Instead of trying to "unconsume" the losing elements, you can pass them along in the next recursive call.

### Hint 2

You can avoid having to accumulate more than one losing element by indicating which side lost last.

### Hint 3

I often find it easier to sketch out an implementation using ordinary collections first when I'm working with Scalaz streams. Here's the helper method we'll need for lists:

```
/**
 * @param p if true, the first of the pair wins
 */
def mergeListsWithHeld[A](p: (A, A) => Boolean)(held: Either[A, A])(
  ls: List[A],
  rs: List[A]
): List[A] = held match {
  // Right is the current winner.
  case Left(l) => rs match {
    // ...but it's empty.
    case Nil => l :: ls
    // ...and it's still winning.
    case r :: rt if p(r, l) => r :: mergeListsWithHeld(p)(held)(ls, rt)
    // ...upset!
    case r :: rt => l :: mergeListsWithHeld(p)(Right(r))(ls, rt)
  }
  // Left is the current winner.
  case Right(r) => ls match {
    case Nil => r :: rs
    case l :: lt if p(l, r) => l :: mergeListsWithHeld(p)(held)(lt, rs)
    case l :: lt => r :: mergeListsWithHeld(p)(Left(l))(lt, rs)
  }
}
```

That assumes we've already got a losing element in hand, but now we can write the method we actually want to use:

```
def mergeListsWith[A](p: (A, A) => Boolean)(ls: List[A], rs: List[A]): List[A] =
  ls match {
    case Nil => rs
    case l :: lt => rs match {
      case Nil => ls
      case r :: rt if p(l, r) => l :: mergeListsWithHeld(p)(Right(r))(lt, rt)
      case r :: rt            => r :: mergeListsWithHeld(p)(Left(l))(lt, rt)
    }
  }
```

And then:

```
scala> org.scalacheck.Prop.forAll { (ls: List[Int], rs: List[Int]) =>
     |   mergeListsWith[Int](_ < _)(ls.sorted, rs.sorted) == (ls ++ rs).sorted
     | }.check
+ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

Okay, looks fine. There are nicer ways we could write this for lists, but this implementation matches the shape of what we'll need to do for `Process`.

## Implementation

And here's more or less the equivalent with scalaz-stream:

```
import scalaz.{ -\/, \/, \/- }
import scalaz.stream.Process.{ awaitL, awaitR, emit }
import scalaz.stream.{ Process, Tee, tee }

def mergeWithHeld[A](p: (A, A) => Boolean)(held: A \/ A): Tee[A, A, A] =
  held.fold(_ => awaitR[A], _ => awaitL[A]).awaitOption.flatMap {
    case None =>
      emit(held.merge) ++ held.fold(_ => tee.passL, _ => tee.passR)
    case Some(next) if p(next, held.merge) =>
      emit(next) ++ mergeWithHeld(p)(held)
    case Some(next) =>
      emit(held.merge) ++ mergeWithHeld(p)(
        held.fold(_ => \/-(next), _ => -\/(next))
      )
  }

def mergeWith[A](p: (A, A) => Boolean): Tee[A, A, A] =
  awaitL[A].awaitOption.flatMap {
    case None => tee.passR
    case Some(l) => awaitR[A].awaitOption.flatMap {
      case None =>               emit(l) ++ tee.passL
      case Some(r) if p(l, r) => emit(l) ++ mergeWithHeld(p)(\/-(r))
      case Some(r)            => emit(r) ++ mergeWithHeld(p)(-\/(l))
    }
  }
```

And lets check it again:

```
scala> org.scalacheck.Prop.forAll { (ls: List[Int], rs: List[Int]) =>
     |   Process.emitAll(ls.sorted).tee(Process.emitAll(rs.sorted))(
     |     mergeWith(_ < _)
     |   ).toList == (ls ++ rs).sorted
     | }.check
+ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

I wouldn't put this into production without some more testing, but it looks like it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a custom tee, as Travis Brown suggested. Here is my [implementation](https://gist.github.com/stormy-ua/5df9749a1861ccf93a752ef667240cbf#file-predicatetee-scala) of the tee:

```
/*
  A tee which sequentially compares elements from left and right
  and passes an element from left if predicate returns true, otherwise
  passes an element from right.
 */
def predicateTee[A](predicate: (A, A) => Boolean): Tee[A, A, A] = {

  def go(stack: Option[A \/ A]): Tee[A, A, A] = {
    def stackEither(l: A, r: A) =
      if (predicate(l, r)) emit(l) ++ go(\/-(r).some) else emit(r) ++ go(-\/(l).some)

    stack match {
      case None =>
        awaitL[A].awaitOption.flatMap { lo =>
          awaitR[A].awaitOption.flatMap { ro =>
            (lo, ro) match {
              case (Some(l), Some(r)) => stackEither(l, r)
              case (Some(l), None) => emit(l) ++ passL
              case (None, Some(r)) => emit(r) ++ passR
              case _ => halt
            }
          }
        }
      case Some(-\/(l)) => awaitR[A].awaitOption.flatMap {
        case Some(r) => stackEither(l, r)
        case None => emit(l) ++ passL
      }
      case Some(\/-(r)) => awaitL[A].awaitOption.flatMap {
        case Some(l) => stackEither(l, r)
        case None => emit(r) ++ passR
      }
    }
  }

  go(None)
}

val p1: Process[Task, Int] = Process(1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11)
val p2: Process[Task, Int] = Process(0, 3, 7, 8, 6)

p1.tee(p2)(predicateTee(_ < _)).runLog.run
//res0: IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 6, 9, 10, 11)
```